# How did 搭 + 訕 compound to mean 'strike up a conversation' or 'reply evasively'?

Tags: etymology

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary). I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

1. The 搭 in [搭訕](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%90%AD%E8%A8%95) doesn't make sense to me. 搭 doesn't mean 'strike up' or 'reply'.
2. What exactly does 訕 mean? The embarrassing context?

Answer (score 2):

From Zdic (汉典), [搭](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%90%AD) has also the meaning of "to come into contact, to meet":

> 3. 交接，配合：～配。～伙。～档。～售。～伴。～帮。～腔。～话。～界。**～讪**。

The last one in the above entry is exactly the example of 搭讪.

The same dictionary provides an entry for 讪 (but also [MDGB does](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%AE%AA)), where it's shown that 讪 alone means "to mock, to ridicule".

So 搭讪 together is somewhat an extension of the two meanings of 搭 and 讪, like *to meet a mocking* (meet = counter). MDGB again gives "to end an embarrassing silence by striking up a conversation", and Zdic "勉强找话说以消除尴尬".

---

PS: I vividly suggest you include Zdic in your preferred vocabulary sources. Even though the interface is in Chinese, you can easily copy-paste characters in the search bar and get decent results.

PS 2: I'm not sure why you think that words composed of 2+ characters must absolutely reflect preexisting meanings of the single characters. Languages can be productive.

Comment: Thanks. "I'm not sure why you think that words composed of 2+ characters must absolutely reflect preexisting meanings of the single characters. Languages can be productive." I don't think this. You're correct. I just have difficulty with semantic shifts.